# Crystal Reports, Database Logon Failed in asp.net while using SQL library

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I am new to visual Studio asp.net and trying to view my crystal report in new tab in PDF format. But I have an issue of login failure.

My code:

```
protected void Show_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Path); 
        try
        {
            
            con.Open();
            string cmd = "select * from [Vw_CMI_AllExceptClosed] where Div_Name ='GUJRANWALA'";
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            sda.Fill(ds);

            rd = new ReportDocument();
            
            rd.Load(Server.MapPath("~/CMI_Reports/Directory_CMI_All.rpt"));
            rd.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "1234", "DEO-05", "CIS");
            rd.SetDataSource(ds.Tables["Vw_CMI_AllExceptClosed"]);

            //******* Code For Opening in Report Viewer in Same Tab  *******//

            //CrystalReportViewer1.ToolPanelView = ToolPanelViewType.None;
            //CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rd;

          
            Session.Add("report", rd);


            //rd.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "1234", "DEO-05", "CIS");
            //************  Code For Opening in New Tab   *****************//
            rd.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, HttpContext.Current.Response, false, "Crystal");
            Response.End();

            //con.Close();
            //Session.Add("report", rd);


        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
        }

        con.Close();

    }
```

where am I wrong? although this is working for CrystalReportview.

Comment: Why do you have a catch statement that just hides any error that might happen?

Comment: Yes, but in this case, the exception of Database login Failure is cached  during debugging